# Static replacement for malloc calls

Tags: c, embedded, u-boot, bare-metal

I am developing a baremetal application. I am looking to adopt U-Boot source code for my application. I want to replace the following malloc calls found in U-Boot to statically allocate memory instead -

```
struct foo *ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct foo));
```

As per my understanding, this line only attempts to allocate enough space for one instance of the structure, and stores the address of that space in ptr.

Hence, I attempted to replace it with the following lines -

```
struct foo *ptr;
int struct_sz = sizeof(struct foo);
char buf[struct_sz];
ptr = &buf;     //also tried ptr = buf;
```

However, this results in Stack Buffer Overflows with the return addresses of functions in the call stack being overwritten with junk.

How do I statically allocate memory instead of using malloc here?

Comment: "However, this results in Stack Buffer Overflows with the return addresses of functions". Show us that code. Sounds like you are trying to return the address of a local variable from a function but can't be sure unless you show the code. If that is the case the options are to use static memory as you have mentioned. But what type of static memory and how to code it depends on the context of your code which you have not shown.

Comment: If you want a static item of type `struct foo`, then why not `static struct foo myfoo;` ?

Comment: @SteveFriedl That could be the case but it depends on how the `ptr` in the original code is used. For example, if it is returned from a function call and multiple instances of the returned memory needs to exist at the same time then a simple static variable would be insufficient (think of something like `strdup`).

Comment: @kaylum The code in question is the sha256 implementation from U-Boot. The malloc line in question is https://elixir.bootlin.com/u-boot/latest/source/common/hash.c#L64

Comment: In that case you may not be able to simply use `static struct foo myfoo;`. Because that would mean that there can only be one `ctx` for the entire program. That could be ok if that condition is true but you will need to analyse the code to determine that. But in general to do it properly you may need to write your own mallocator which allocates from static memory. Depending on the constraints you could make that really simple - e.g. fixed array of `static struct foo mybuffers[MAX_CONTEXTS]` and then return memory from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is allocating an array of characters and then having a pointer to a struct as pointing to the same memory.

While this is possible, you can run into memory alignment issues. The structure might have a requirement to start at a particular yte location. (e.g. a 32 bit int needs to start an address of a multiple of 4). A character array can start at any location.

An easier approach would be to declare a variable of `struct foo` and use the pointer to that variable. This variable needs to be global or static so that it will be present after the function scope is completed.

```
static struct foo var;
struct foo *ptr = &var;
```

To allocate many structs, you need a static array of structs

```
static struct arr[5];
struct foo *ptr = arr;
```

This approach will work if you allocate memory and do not free it very often. If you have many `malloc` and `free` you should consider writing your own allocator which will mimic the functionality of `malloc`

Comment: You also need to watch out for **the chuminess of C** type structures http://c-faq.com/struct/structhack.html

Comment: "While this is possible, you can run into memory alignment issues" And it's also undefined behavior because of strict aliasing. It simply doesn't make sense to cast a char array to a struct.

Comment: Thanks, this works! I tried creating a variable of the struct but forgot to make it static. Brain fade..